# Meaning of "quantitative result"

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, soft-question, geometric-measure-theory, definitions

Recently I've begun reading on metric measure spaces and I keep seeing statements containing the phrase ", quantitatively".  What does this mean, I googled it and couldn't find a rigorous answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantitative is typically used as opposed to qualitative. In the geometric context referred to by the OP, the distinction is explained as follows:

> Quantitative geometry and topology refines the qualitative, discrete
>   questions of algebraic and geometric topology into continuous ones.
>   For example, we may see a loop in a space which is homotopically
>   trivial and ask how difficult it is to trivialize. Depending on what
>   we mean by "difficult", we might obtain different notions of
>   isoperimetry; one common choice is the area of a filling disk, which
>   leads to the definition of the Dehn function of a group.
>
> A priori, such notions usually depend on the choice of a metric on the
>   space; one can then analyze their dependence on the metric
>   (quantitative geometry) or show results, for example asymptotic ones,
>   which are independent of the choice (quantitative topology).

[source](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~manin//qgt-workshop.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering this.  I've always been confused; though it seems still like a bit of a slang

Comment: More generally it’s proving not just an inequality but an estimate of the difference in terms of interesting quantities related to the inequality.